# Contract deployment exceeds block gas limit

Tags: mist, gas, erc-20

I am using the mist wallet to deploy the standard ERC20 contract that it provides in its tutorial. in my wallet has 0.05 ether, but whenever I try to deploy the contract, even at the cheapest possible mining speed I get an error message

`exceeds block gas limit`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi there. By _"cheapest possible mining speed"_ do you mean the lowest amount of gas? What settings are you using in Mist when deploying the contract?

Comment: On the fee slider, I set it to the cheaper side

Comment: @OscarChambers The block gas limit is to prevent malicious attacks to the Ethereum network. If you contract is too big it will generate that error, it cannot be changed without the approval of the majority of the miners. One alternative is to 'trim' your contract, another is to split into several smaller contracts.

Comment: You should try to minimize the gas amount that you are passing during transaction.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is related to the gaslimit set in the init genesis file - I had the same issue. I had to delete my blockchain, increase the gaslimit parameter in the genesis.json, rebuild the blockchain, etc - and then it worked no problem.